# "Software Index is Broken"

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, package-management, chrome

I'm trying to install a Chrome update on Linux Mint "Quiana". I downloaded the .deb file; when I try to open/run/install it, GDebi Package Installer
says:

> Software Index is Broken
>
> This is a major failure of your software management system. Please check for broken packages with synaptic, check the file permissions and correctness of the file '/etc/apt/sources.list' and reload the software information with: 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get install -f'.

So I try  to run synaptic to check for broken packages. It won't
start; says

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

Now what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Synaptic can’t start, skip the part that depends on it (which isn’t obvious), and run the last two commands given in the message:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

The `update` is the part which will take care of the software indexes.

If you have an invalid index which doesn’t match a repository in your configuration, it won’t be fixed (but I would have thought it wouldn’t be references either). To handle that, delete all the indexes and update:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

If the error persists after that, that suggests the index is corrupt in the repository you’re downloading from. To get past it, delete the specific index `gdebi` is complaining about:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en
```

and *don’t* run `apt-get update` before trying to install your package again. Such errors should fix themselves at the next mirror pulse (within twelve hours or so).

Comment: Thanks. Tried that before posting the question; no joy. Searching for the error message I saw someone somewhere else say try "sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf" first. Now synaptic runs, finds no broken packages. GDeb starts, spends some time trying to install the .deb, complains about dependencies. (Have to go to work, will try again tomorrow....)

Comment: Yes, the `rm` would have been my next suggestion.

Comment: Thx again. Error message said I should run "gksudo synaptic". Now synaptic finds a broken package google-chrome-stable . ???

Comment: I bet I got the wrong download. Any hints how to upgrade Chrome on Mint? I don't see it listed on the "other distributions" page - maybe it's there with a synonym I don't recognize.

Comment: For Mint the appropriate download is “64 bit .deb (For Debian/Ubuntu)” (Mint is based on Ubuntu and pulls most of its packages from Ubuntu). You might get more useful information by running `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/google-chrome...deb` in a terminal window, instead of using `gdebi`.

Comment: That's the one I tried first. Ok,  so next I download another copy. Really have to go to  work - I hate that...

Comment: Got it working - thx. Must  have fixed a lot of crap  -  the  Mint "Software Manager" is working for the first time in a while. (Bad attitude: never seemed cost-effective to try to fix it until I actually wanted to manage some software...)